# How do I check for separate classes using `is_a?`?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to define a method that returns `true` if an array contains a string or a number. I want this method to return:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, "string" ]
any_strings_or_numbers?(a)
#=> true

b = [ "no numbers" ]
any_strings_or_numbers?(b)
#=> true

c = [ 1.0 ]
any_strings_or_numbers?(c)
#=> true

c = [ ]
any_strings_or_numbers?(c)
#=> false
```

This is what I tried, and it is not working:

```
def any_strings_or_numbers?(a)
  a.any? {|num| num.is_a?(String || Integer) }
end
```

Comment: `num` is a misleading variable name if you expect both, numbers and strings.

Answer (score 2):

You missed that there are several number classes in ruby.

```
1.class 
# => Fixnum

(2**65).class
# => Bignum

1.0.class
# => Float
```

The superclass for all numbers is `Numeric`. So you probably want to know if the object is an instance of a subclass of `Numeric` or `String`.

```
def any_strings_or_numbers?(a)
  a.any? {|x| x.kind_of?(String) || x.kind_of?(Numeric) }
end
```

Comment: You mean an instance of a subclass.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  how do you get it to return true if a it has a floating point number only?

Comment: @kelsonpw You really need to show some effort, it's not that hard.

Comment: @kelsonpw just only ask for x.kind_of? (Float). or did you mean the array should contain exactly one single float? Thís would be another question....

Answer (score 1):

```
def any_strings_or_numbers?(a)
  a.any? {|num| case num; when String, Integer then true; end}
end
```

Comment: For additional, case in this instance is same as `String === num || Integer === num`, difference only that `case` returns `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  how do you get it to return true if a it has a floating point number only?

Comment: @kelsonpw You really need to show some effort, it's not that hard.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, would you get **any element is an instance of** or **all elements are instances of**? In most real life cases we check for all elements, I am just curious, may be your case is a special :) Let me suggest this way:

```
collection.any? do |element|
  [String, Numeric].any? { |klass| element.is_a? klass }
end
```

By this way it is easy to add more possible classes, parametrize whitelist or extract verification to method.

PS. If you need *all* elements being instances of classes from the whitelist, than use **all?** for the top level iteration.